# Add a hyperlink to an image in a cell that references another worksheet in the document using EPPlus

Tags: image, excel, hyperlink, epplus

Need a little help on EPPlus , I've insert an image and would like the image to be hyperlink to a different sheet ( Table of Content ). The AddImage function accepts a Uri object for the Hyperlink property but would not accept any cell value.

Here's my code

```
private static void AddImage(ExcelWorksheet ws, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, string filePath,int offset,string optionalHyperLinkURL = "")
{

    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(filePath);
    ExcelPicture picture = null;
    if (image != null)
    {
        if (optionalHyperLinkURL != ""){
            // it's crashing here because I can't pass in [XXXXX.xlsx]'TOC!A1' as the hyperlink since it's not a valid URL
            picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("pic00", image, new Uri(optionalHyperLinkURL)); 

        } 
        else
        {
            picture = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("pic00", image);
        }
        picture.From.Column = columnIndex;
        picture.From.Row = rowIndex;

        picture.From.ColumnOff = Pixel2MTU(offset); //Two pixel space for better alignment
        picture.From.RowOff = Pixel2MTU(2);//Two pixel space for better alignment
        picture.SetSize(386, 138);
    }
}
```

Comment: See if this [article](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.in/2012/07/add-hyper-link-in-excel-using-epplus.html) helps you